Issues with wifi after hard restart
I unwisely restarted my machine by holding the power button and after restart I have no internet connection despite being connected to wifi. I believe I was connected to a vpn when I restarted and I think that's the cause of my issue.
This is the output of the nmcli dev status command:
DEVICE              TYPE            STATE           CONNECTION
wlp3s0              wifi            connected       FRITZ!Box 6660 Cable LB
p2p-dev-wlp3s0      wifi-p2p        disconnected    --
..
..

I have been going under the assumption that the killswitch in the vpn is blocking my internet connection. I've tried reconnecting to the vpn as well as uninstalling it, but those commands run code that is now thowing unhandled exceptions.
I have also tried nmcli device delete p2p-dev-wlp3s0 as well as creating a no-p2p.conf file to block p2p connections in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ followed by restarting the Network Manager. I undid those changed after Network Manager failed to restart. I've also already tried restarting my computer.
The router seems to work fine as other devices are able to access the internet.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I appreciate any help.

I solved it by following this video:
As shown in the video:

Edit or create a file - /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf


Add the lines:
# nameserver ::1
# nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4


Save, exit and retry the internet


